# Python MySQL connector returns bytearray instead of string for prepared statements

Tags: python, mysql

Given MySQL table like such:

```
create table demo (id int, name varchar(100)) collate utf8mb4_general_ci;
insert into demo values (1,'abcdef');
```

And Python script:

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(host='xx', user='xx', password='xx', database='xx')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from demo')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

This produces the expected result:

```
(1, 'abcdef')
```

If I however change the cursor to a prepared cursor:

```
cursor = db.cursor(prepared=True)
```

the result is unexpected:

```
(1, bytearray(b'abcdef'))
```

I'm using Python 3.8.0 and mysql.connecter version 2.2.9
In the release notes of MySQL connector 2.1.8 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-2-1-8.html) I read

> When using prepared statements, string columns were returned as bytearrays instead of strings. The returned value is now a string decoded using the connection's charset (defaults to 'utf8'), or as a bytearray if this conversion fails. (Bug #27364914)

so I did not expect the behavior in the version I'm using.

What am I missing?

Comment: This seems like a bug. FWIW the behaviour is not reproducible in the latest version (8.0.22).  Note this version must be installed with `pip install mysql-connector-python` see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-versions.html

Comment: Thanks for this pointer @snakecharmerb, this fixed my issue, and as a bonus the performance is much better now. But like Booboo below noticed performance with prepared statements seems to be worse than without prepared. Puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

The text should probably read:

> The returned value is now a string ***encoded*** using the connection's charset (defaults to 'utf8'), or as a bytearray if this conversion fails. (Bug #27364914).

```
>>> 'abcdef'.encode('utf8') == b'abcdef'
True
>>>
```

So, when using `cursor = db.cursor(prepared=True)`, the driver is doing what the documentation says it will do (if the encoding fails, only then will it return a `bytearray`, but otherwise expect a byte string -- *this is the change being describe*d). But I see no reason to specify `prepared=True` for you can use prepared statements without that and get the results you have come to expect if you are only using the prepared statement as a mechanism to avoid SQL Injection attacks and are not using it for repetitive execution.

**Update**

I did a small benchmark with and without using `prepared=True` retrieving 10,882 rows:

```
import mysql.connector

def foo(db):
    cursor = db.cursor(prepared=True)
    for i in range(10883):
        cursor.execute('select Company from company where PK_Company = %s', (i,))
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows[0][0]) # print last fetched row

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='xx', password='xx', database='xx')
foo(db)
```

Results:

```
With `prepared=True`: 2.0 seconds for function `foo`
Without `prepeared=True`: 1.6 seconds for function `foo`
Using pymysql: 1.5 seconds for function `foo`
```

It would seem that `prepared=True` runs more slowly. ????

Comment: How can I use prepared statements without prepared=True? As far as I understand without that the sql-statement will get interpreted in every execute. So if I call the same sql-statement 1 million times with different parameters it is very much not as efficient as using real prepared statements.

Comment: I use `pymysql` for MySql access and with that driver I think the only benefits you get from prepared statements is sql injection avoidance and data conversion but that may not be the case with `mysql.connector` using `cursor(prepared=True)`. Hopefully, at least I explained why you are getting the results you are getting. I will update the answer and modify the last sentence.